# Using the derived class when deriving a from a class template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I wanted to write three wrapper classes for `Day`, `Month` and `Year` that basically only wrap an `int`. My goal was to get some type-safety and can not accidently switch parameters for a function like `void date(int y, int m, int d)`.

When I was done I noticed that the three classes share much code. So I decided I want to derive them from a base class: `Value`. That base class will also implement `operator+`, but it has to return `Year` (or `Month`, or `Day`), and not `Value`. So I went for a bit of derive-from-a-template magic.

And Lo and Behold: it works -- almost.

The `operator<<` compiles, because `Derived&´ can be resolved.

But `operator+=` tries to return `Derived&` from `*this`, which is a `Value&`.

```
template<class Derived>
class Value {
protected:
    int value_;
public:
    explicit Value(int v) : value_{v} {}
    int value() const { return value_; }
    Derived& operator+=(const Derived& other) {
        value_ += other.value_;
        return *this;                               // ERROR!
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Derived& x) {
        return os << x.value_;
    }
};

class Year2 : public Value<Year2> {
public:
    explicit Year2(int v) : Value<Year2>(v) {}     // NOTICE <Year2>
    bool isLeap() const { return value_ % 4 == 0; };
};
```

I have the feeling, I am almost there. **Is it possible to use this kind of template-derive-magic and implement operator+= ?**

In addition, to my amazement my gcc-4.9.0 has been agnostic to how I call the base constructor. The following worked too:

```
class Year3 : public Value<Year3> {
public:
    explicit Year3(int v) : Value(v) {}            // NOTICE no <...>
    bool isLeap() const { return value_ % 4 == 0; };
};
```

**Did I do something wrong with the base c'tor call?** Or is it gcc? Or is there a difference?

Comment: `return *(static_cast<Derived*>(this));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `static_cast` this to return the correct pointer.

```
return *(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
```

Or

```
return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
```

---

However it seems like this might be unnecessary. It seems you don't really to make the Value class a template. Is there a reason for this?

Isn't this enough?

```
class Value {
protected:
    int value_;
public:
    explicit Value(int v) : value_{v} {}
    int value() const { return value_; }
    Value& operator+=(const Value& other) {
        value_ += other.value_;
        return *this;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Value& x) {
        return os << x.value_;
    }
};

class Year2 : public Value {
public:
    explicit Year2(int v) : Value(v) {}
    bool isLeap() const { return value_ % 4 == 0; };
};

int main()
{
    Year2 y1(1), y2(2);
    y1 += y2;
    cout << y1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I guess you are right, no need for a template. I wanted the correct return type, so I thought I should parameterize that type. And since I do not use `virtual` I wasn't really thinking polymorphic. I guess my brain has two modes in which it works: The `virtual` polymorphic one and the static types template one. Sometimes those brain areas should talk with each other...

To your `static_cast` -- yes that will work of course, and I did not think of that either. But: Since that kind of cast is evil it invalidates my whole "solution".